# regex pattern for following double value

Tags: android, regex

I have values like
 0009
 90.20
90.00

I want ans 
 9
90.20
 90

how I can get it 
right now I am doing

```
Amount.setText(Integer.toString((int) amount));
Amount.getText().toString().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

but I am getting wrong values

Comment: what you getting??

Answer (score 0):

```
 string s = "0009 90.20 90.00";
            s = s.TrimStart('0').TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.').Trim();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.Read();

//9 90.20 90
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to get rid of the last decimal part.

```
Amount.getText().toString().replaceAll("^0+|\\.\\d+$", "");
```

or

```
Amount.getText().toString().replaceAll("^0+|\\.0+$", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yV0rD2/1)